# Javascript Animation Positioning and Scaling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm currently working on a single screen which has multiple `content views` which will be accessed from a button to the side of the dynamic area. I found this repo (https://github.com/ian-de-vries/Multi-Screen.js) which achieves something very similar to what I want, only it expects a full screen, as opposed to just a certain area. So far, I've got it very close to performing as I would hope, but the last couple of hours have had me stumped. Currently there are two issues:

1) The relative `divs` use the `% width` value of their containing `div`, while the animation of the `divs` uses a `% width` of the entire `screen`, making the animated `divs` larger. I think the way around this is to calculate the `fixed width` during the animation then remove it post animation. If you set a `fixed width` in the `css` (which isn't appropriate for the site) the animation is smooth and has the correct `width` whilst animating, but then leads to the next issue.

2) Because of the original functionality of the `js`, the animations come straight down the centre, which again adds to a worse animation because of the `offset content`.

While I've tried to solve both of these issues, `JS` is beyond me despite the experience I have in other programming languages. I thought I was onto something when editing the `pre/post/animation_css` `variables`, but I couldn't get what I wanted to achieve. Anyway, below is a quick dummy site which replicates the code on the actual site well, and creates the same issues. To get this working, put these two files in a folder with the `multi-screen.js` file from the repo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Scrolling Pages -->
    <!-- latest jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- link the css and js scripts -->
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="multi-screen.js"></script>

    <!-- run the plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { MultiScreen.init(); });</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">My Header</div>
    <div class="contentarea">


<div style="float:left; width: 20%; background-color: red; height: 500pt;"></div>

<div style="width:80%; float: right; height: 600pt; background-color: grey;">

<div id="entry_screen" class="ms-container ms-default" style="">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="screen2" data-ms-exit-animation="top" data-ms-enter-animation="bottom">go down</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="screen3" data-ms-exit-animation="top" data-ms-enter-animation="bottom">go down 2</a>

</div>

<div id="screen2" class="ms-container" style="">


    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="entry_screen" data-ms-exit-animation="bottom" data-ms-enter-animation="top">go up</a><br>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="screen3" data-ms-exit-animation="top" data-ms-enter-animation="bottom">go down</a>


    </div>

    <div id="screen3" class="ms-container" style="">

           <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="screen2" data-ms-exit-animation="bottom" data-ms-enter-animation="top">go up</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-nav-link" data-ms-target="entry_screen" data-ms-exit-animation="bottom" data-ms-enter-animation="top">go up 2</a>


</div>
</div>
</div><!---------- Close "content-area" --------->
</div><!---------- Close "wrapper" --------->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.ms-container {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
display: none;
}

.ms-default {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
}

#entry_screen {
height: 500pt; 
width: 80%; 
background-color: green; 
left: 0;
margin-left: 20%;
}

#screen2 {
height: 500pt;
width: 80%; 
//float: right; 
background-color: blue; 
//margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 20%;

}

#screen3 {
height: 500pt;
width: 80%; 
background-color: magenta;
margin-left: 20%;
}

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0  10% 0 10%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 0pt;
}

.contentarea {
position: relative;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 50pt;
 }

a {
    color: white;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using another alternative. The one I chose was fullPage.js. It can be used for the desired functionally despite being for full screen sites. Hope this helps anyone who wanted to achieve something similar.